# Creating A Local Working SVN Copy Via C#?

Tags: c#, svn

Is it possible to create a new local working SVN copy from a specified repository using C# code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this using [sharpsvn](http://sharpsvn.open.collab.net/) (or any .NET wrapper for SVN).  This is used by many SVN clients (such as AnkhSvn and MonoDevelop) for all of their SVN bindings, and supports pretty much the entire set of SVN commands.

Comment: wouldn't it be fair to spend more than 1 minute looking at the library just introduced to you, before you ask a follow up question? I'm sure we will help you out with questions down the road, but you can't expect us to write the thing for you, seeing as you haven't even decided on your approach for yourself yet :)

Comment: Yeah, that is fair.  I tend to ask a lot from StackOverflow *Goes and searches for command*

Comment: @sooprise: The command, btw, is `CheckOut` on the client class - it takes a Uri (for the repo) and a local path

Answer (score 0):

you can run a command line from c# ... use (check documentation for correct syntax)

```
svnadmin hotcopy [source] [destination]
```